# imacros puts focus on button, but will not press it

Tags: javascript, imacros

FF 42.0 / Imacros for FF BUILD=8940826 / 2.8Ghz 8 core Early 2008 MacPro / OSX 10.8.2

This seems like it should be so simple.  I just want to hit the search button and enter a search term.

```
TAB T=1
SET !REPLAYSPEED SLOW
URL GOTO=https://play.spotify.com/browse
WAIT SECONDS=5
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=DATA-HREF:suggest&&ID:nav-search*
FRAME F=1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ACTION:# ATTR=TYPE:text&&DATA-TA-ID:input&&CLASS:form-control<SP>focus CONTENT=chromeo
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=DRAGGABLE:true&&DATA-DRAG-TEXT:Chromeo&&DATA-URI:spotify:artist:2mV8aJphiSHYJf43DxL7Gt
```

Macro should press the search button which expands to show a dialog box where search term can be entered.  Instead, it puts the button in focus, but never presses it, and so the rest never happens.

I've spent many hours wrestling with this and searched every related thing I could think of and come up with nothing.  The line after the wait is the one that should be pressing the button.  As far as I can tell, it looks like it's saying to press the button.  I can't find any discussion of this phenomenon or reference to something that FORCES a button push if macro merely puts the button in focus.

Only thing I can even think of to try next would be maybe porting it all over into .js file and see if I can get the javascript to execute a button press... but I'm grasping at straws here.  It is RECOGNIZING the button.  I mean, if I change the text so it doesn't match, it will tell me it can't find it.  It is finding it... just not pressing it.

Comment: Provide an html-code of the problem button.

Comment: Solution furnished elsewhere and now updated here.  This has led to another related question with this solution now implemented here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33746955/imacros-firefox-cannot-replicate-this-website-button-press-in-any-record-mode          Since you asked for the button html here, I included it in the question linked.

Answer (score 0):

Solved elsewhere via event mode.

```
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR=\"#nav-search\" BUTTON=0
```